# Drupal 7: Generating HTML e-mail depending on chosen term and node

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-nodes

I want to make ability for anonymous users to get e-mail with discount coupon for manually chosen product.

It could be put in one form (select lists) or multiple steps (product selection > user info)

How it should work:

1. User in page/block chooses taxonomy term (category of product)
2. User chooses node (filtered by chosen taxonomy term)
3. User inputs name, e-mail.
4. User clicks submit button
5. Html e-mail is being generated and sent with user name, chosen node title and custom field from that node with discount rate.

Is it difficult to achieve it work?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for can be recreated with the Webform module (https://drupal.org/project/webform), Simply create a webform with your desired fields (category, node, name, email) and then customize the receipt to use the [node:discount-code] token for the user's chosen node.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer Matt. I tried this Webform module, it's almost that I need, but how prevent category select list to be auto filled by  taxonomy terms, and node select list to be auto filled by node titles (filtered by chosen category).

Comment: Filtering the nodes available based on a taxonomy is a bit more complex. What you need to do is when you're creating your entity reference field you have to point it towards an 'entity reference view' which will push out the nodes required based on some preset conditions. If you have a multistep form you should be able to get the previous values from a URL, in which case that can be fed through to a contextual filter set on the view.